# Read localstate by chrome-extension

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to pass arguments from selenium to my chrome-extension in the moment of creating new selenium session. I could pass all arguments using [setLocalState](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html#setLocalState), but I have no idea how to read these options by chrome-extension. 
Currently what I'm doing is:

1. create new selenium session with my chrome-extension
2. open specific url and add all arguments in query string. Chrome is waiting for this url and then parse query string to get these arguments.

Is it possible to pass arguments from selenium and read them by chrome-extension without doing any extra step apart from creating new session with arguments passed in `Capabilities`?

It's possible In Firefox using `profile preferences`, but cannot find any way to do that in chrome

Comment: I see no extension API to access `Local State` contents directly or indirectly. BTW it's not related to a user profile.